# How can I update user online status without reloading the controller?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, user-presence

So I have made a working Chat app where the back end is Firestore (i know firebase is there.) I also have a document where users online offline status is recorder.

When the user logs in the "isOnline" node changes the value to true or "online" and when the app goes in background the value changes to "offline".

The only problem is i have to reload the viewController to make the changes take place. Is there any way I can update the users status real time

AppDelegate:-

in ApplicationDidBecomeActive

```
 if User.currentUser() != nil {
                updateCurrentUserInFirestore(withValues: [kISONLINE : "online"]) { (success) in
                }
            }
```

in ApplicationDidEnterBackground

```
if User.currentUser() != nil {
            updateCurrentUserInFirestore(withValues: [kISONLINE : "offline"]) { (success) in

            }
        }
```

Than in chatViewController setup of the navigation bar is as follows

```
userstatus func
     if withUser.isOnline == "online" {
                navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.flatGreen()
            }else{
               navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.flatBlue()
            }
```

below is the function to check the change in status

```
 func updateUserOnlineStatus() {

        if !isGroup! {
            var withUser = withUsers.first!


            withUserUpdateListener = reference(.User).document(withUser.isOnline).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
                guard let snapshot = snapshot else {  return }
                if snapshot.exists {
                    print(snapshot)
                   let withUser = User(_dictionary: snapshot.data()! as NSDictionary)
                   self.setUIForSingleChat(withUser: withUser)
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Well, you could create some observable class which informs observing objects of state changes. Then in your viewController you'd add yourself as an observer, and you'll get notified once a user logs in, or out. Alternatively you could use `NSNotification` and `NSNotificationCenter` to notify your viewController something changed.

Answer (score 0):

This did the trick there was some problem in the old code

```
func updateUserOnlineStatus() {
    print("User update online status")
    if !isGroup! {
        var withUser = withUsers.first!
        withUserUpdateListener = reference(.User).document(withUser.objectId).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            if error != nil {
               print("error")
            }
            print("update user status")
            let withUser = FUser(_dictionary: snapshot!.data()! as NSDictionary)
            if withUser.isOnline == "online" {
                self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.flatGreen()
            }else{
               self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.flatBlue()
            }


            }

        }

    }
```